# How to get node information on Spark Decision Tree model

Tags: python, scala, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I'd like to have more detailed information on each node of the generated model by Spark MLlib's Decision Tree. The closest I could get using the API is `print(model.toDebugString())`, which returns something like this (taken from the PySpark doc)

```
  DecisionTreeModel classifier of depth 1 with 3 nodes
  If (feature 0 <= 0.0)
   Predict: 0.0
  Else (feature 0 > 0.0)
   Predict: 1.0
```

How can I modify the MLlib source code in order to get, for instance, the impurity and depth of each node? (and if necessary, how can I call the new Scala function in PySpark?)

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to complement @mostOfMajority's answer by describing how I have done it using PySpark 2.4.3.

### Root Node

Given a trained Decision Tree model, this is how you can get its root node:

```
def _get_root_node(tree: DecisionTreeClassificationModel):
    return tree._call_java('rootNode')
```

### Impurities

We can get the impurities by walking down the tree from the root node. Its [pre-order transversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order_(NLR)) could be done like this:

```
def get_impurities(tree: DecisionTreeClassificationModel) -> List[float]:
    def recur(node):
        if node.numDescendants() == 0:
            return []
        ni = node.impurity()
        return (
            recur(node.leftChild()) + [ni] + recur(node.rightChild())
        )
    return recur(_get_root_node(tree))
```

#### Example

```
In [1]: print(tree.toDebugString)
DecisionTreeClassificationModel (uid=DecisionTreeClassifier_f90ba6dbb0fe) of depth 3 with 7 nodes
  If (feature 0 <= 6.5)
   If (feature 0 <= 3.5)
    Predict: 1.0
   Else (feature 0 > 3.5)
    If (feature 0 <= 5.0)
     Predict: 0.0
    Else (feature 0 > 5.0)
     Predict: 1.0
  Else (feature 0 > 6.5)
   Predict: 0.0


In [2]: cat.get_impurities(tree)
Out[2]: [0.4444444444444444, 0.5, 0.5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I could not find any way to access nodes *directly* in PySpark or Spark (Scala API). But there is a way to start from a root node and traverse to different nodes.

(I just mentioned impurity here, but for depth one could easily substitute, `impurity` with `subtreeDepth`.)

Assuming the Decision Tree Model instance is `dt`:

## PySpark

```
root = dt.call("topNode")
root.impurity() # gives the impurity of the root node
```

Now if we look at the methods applicable to `root`:

```
dir(root)
[u'apply', u'deepCopy', u'emptyNode', u'equals', 'getClass', u'getNode', u'hashCode', u'id', 'impurity', u'impurity_$eq', u'indexToLevel', u'initializeLogIfNecessary', u'isLeaf', u'isLeaf_$eq', u'isLeftChild', u'isTraceEnabled', u'leftChildIndex', u'leftNode', u'leftNode_$eq', u'log', u'logDebug', u'logError', u'logInfo', u'logName', u'logTrace', u'logWarning', u'maxNodesInLevel', u'notify', u'notifyAll', u'numDescendants', u'org$apache$spark$internal$Logging$$log_', u'org$apache$spark$internal$Logging$$log__$eq', u'parentIndex', u'predict', u'predict_$eq', u'rightChildIndex', u'rightNode', u'rightNode_$eq', u'split', u'split_$eq', u'startIndexInLevel', u'stats', u'stats_$eq', u'subtreeDepth', u'subtreeIterator', u'subtreeToString', u'subtreeToString$default$1', u'toString', u'wait']
```

We could do:

```
root.leftNode().get().impurity()
```

And this could go deeper in the tree, e.g.:

```
root.leftNode().get().rightNode().get().impurity()
```

Since after applying `leftNode()` or `rightNode()`, we get to an `option`, applying `get` or getOrElse`is necessary to get to the desired`Node` type.

If you wonder how I got to these strange methods, I gotta admit, I cheated!!, i.e. I looked into Scala API first:

## Spark

The following lines are exact equivalent of those above and give the same results assuming `dt` is the same:

```
val root = dt.topNode
root.impurity
```

We could do:

```
root.leftNode.get.impurity
```

And this could go deeper in the tree, e.g.:

```
root.leftNode.get.rightNode.get.impurity
```

Comment: Decision Tree Model Instance doesn't have  call() method in pyspark 2.3. What version of spark are you using?

Comment: This was with pyspark 2.2.1. Have not tried 2.3 yet.

Comment: @sgu did you find a solution for pyspark2.3  ?